# Can you exclude hidden DOM elements from Chrome find function?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, search, iframe, find

I've set up a single .html document that uses tabs for navigation. There are also sub-tabs for navigating inside major sections. This is accomplished with iframes and jQuery .show() / .hide() functionality, essentially hiding and showing  elements.

The problem is that I have several large PDF documents in iframes, and Chrome's Ctrl+F find/search functionality searches every loaded iframe, not just what's visible. Chrome's built-in PDF viewer doesn't allow you to search *only that document* as far as I can see.

Some things I've tried/considered:

- **Custom search function with Javascript:** The PDFs in the iframes are from a different domain, so the contents cannot be accessed.
- **Searching in only certain elements:** The only way to exclude elements is to make them CSS content / make them images / make them SVGs, which doesn't help because, again, I can't access the contents of the iframes.
- **PDF.js or similar plugin solution:** From what I can tell, this also has issues with CORS in Chrome.
- **Removing or changing the src= element of hidden elements:** I can't reliably find a way to check what's visible on the page and what isn't.

```html
<div id="pdf1" class="tab active">
<iframe class="frame" frameborder="0" style="display:block;" src="pdf1.pdf"></iframe>
</div>
<div id="pdf2" class="tab">
<iframe class="frame" frameborder="0" style="display:none;" src="pdf2.pdf"></iframe>
</div>
```

I'm not even sure if what I'm wanting to achieve is even possible for a start.

My overall question is, can I restrict Chrome's Ctrl+F find function to certain elements - in this case, visible iframes?

**Edit:** Switching from `<iframe>` to `<embed>` fixed this issue - PDFs are less responsive to load now but it's worth it to be able to search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing an iframe's style to `visibility:hidden` results in text inside it being found regardless. But, if you use `display: none`, Chrome's Find will not look inside it:

```html
<iframe srcdoc="<p>Some visible iframe</p>"></iframe>
<iframe srcdoc="<p>Some invisible iframe</p>" style="display: none"></iframe>
```

So if you put all the iframes in static containers (so that page layout doesn't change even if the iframes are changed to `display: none`), and then hide the iframes when not in view (or when control-F is pressed), Chrome's Find will not find text inside them.

([Related issue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381900/))

Comment: Thanks for that - that makes sense. I realise in light of that, my issue now is that iframes in the sub-tabs are being left on `display: block` when I switch away. Will have to have a think about how to reset these to `display: none` - preferably whilst remembering which one was last active!

Comment: Quick update, I've added this script into my project:
`$(".tab-links").click(function() {
        $('iframe').css({"display": ""})
        $('iframe:hidden').css({"display": "none"})
    });`

This definitely adds `display: none` to divs that aren't visible, however Chrome is still showing search results for them. I did a simple test like yours and it seemed to work - any ideas as to what might allow Chrome to still look inside hidden iframes?